# How do I use the value stored in a variable as a method call?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a method that looks like this:

```
> rating
=> "speed"
```

Then I have a call that looks like this:

```
profile.ratings.find_by(user: current_user).speed
```

What I want to do is pass the value of `rating` to that call.

But when I do this:

```
 profile.ratings.find_by(user: current_user).rating
```

It doesn't work, because there is no method called `rating` on each `ratings` object.

This is the error I get when I run the above:

```
  Rating Load (4.5ms)  SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."profile_id" = $1 AND "ratings"."user_id" = 7 LIMIT $2  [["profile_id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `rating' for #<Rating:0x007fca0c4fba90>
```

I would normally do string interpolation, except now I am working on a method call.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to access a property on an ActiveRecord model they provide a simple accessor:

```
profile.ratings.find_by(user: current_user)[rating]
```

This is safer than the `send` method since it's only going to fetch attributes. If you had a method called `ban_and_charge_ten_bucks!` some hostile user might be able your system into calling that if you call `send` without checking what you're calling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [send method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
profile.ratings.find_by(user: current_user).send(rating)
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that if this is user data, **don't** arbitrarily execute it. For reasons of safety it's best to have a white-list of allowed methods.

Comment: @tadman That's exactly what I am doing....I have an array of accepted inputs that I am iterating over. I just need to be able to execute each accordingly.

Comment: If the method names are under your control you're fine here. Just be careful. This is how CVNs are made.